# Submit form in Magento only if already logged in

Tags: forms, magento

I would like to create a form in Magento with some extension. At the bottom of the form , when the user pushes the submit button, if he is not registered and logged in yet, it should redirect him to the "Create New Account" page. But if he is already logged in, he should be able to submit the form and the form should automatically include some details of his account (e.g. username, name, etc). How could I achieve this and which extension should I use for the form?

Comment: You should read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Please check below form action

```
<?php $custmlogin= new Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login();?>
<form action="<?php echo $custmlogin->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
Email:<input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo   $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
Password:<input type="password" name="login[password]" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
<button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
</form>
```